# Giving your self root acces on ftps

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I now have an ubuntu server with a user called `rvdutchman`, I also have a LAMP server running on that server. with using apache2 the dir where you can put your website on is `/var/www/html`. So I login to the site with the `rvdutchman` user with ftps. I am in the `root`, `sudo` and `www-data` group. but when I go to that dir I only can copy things from it. when I try to `rm` or `add` a dir/file I dont have permissons. Is there anyway I can give the user `rvdutchman` that permessions?

Answer (score 0):

Who does the folder /etc/www/html belong to?
Group *root* and User *www-data* or both *www-data* ?
In that case, you can add your user to both groups as you said and for that period you can change the permissions for 0775 and after which you can convert it to 0755

This should help.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.